# Qt, C++ | Обращение к объектам формы

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Вопрос:как из функции-обработчика обратиться к объектам на форме Ui

Создал widget+layout для сscrollArea

```
    ui->setupUi(this);

//====Создаем область компоновки====
QGridLayout* gridl = new QGridLayout;
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);
widget->setLayout(grid);
ui->scrollA->setWidget(widget);
```

В grid необходимо добавлять объекты создаваемые обработчиком нажатия кнопки
Соответственно, строки вроде ui->grid1->addWidget() и различные их вариации не работают и возвращают:
*%имя объекта% was not declared* in this scope

Comment: так просто `grid1`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver , не работает, все та же ошибка

Comment: Вы знакомы с с++ и областями видимости переменных? Если вы хотите использовать указатель grid1 в методах класса вашего окна, его надо объявлять как поле класса, а не как локальную переменную в конструкторе

Answer (score 1):

Класс ui создается при помощи moc на этапе компиляции и если на этом этапе у него нет поля grid1, то оно и не появится в процессе работы программы. Вам следует хранить указатели на эти объекты в классе окна.
Смысл в том, что ui хранить указатели на объекты, созданные в дизайнере, а по команде setupUI(QWidget) инициализирует эти объекты так, как это задано в дизайнере и указанном виджете. Вам же нужно хранить grid1 либо в ui, и тогда нужно нарисовать его в дизайнере, или прямо в классе окна и тогда объявить его в секции private и инициализировать после setupUi.